# Ubuntu 13.04 - High temperature

Tags: 13.04, cpu, temperature

I've always used Ubuntu. I installed the version (13.04) and I have a problem: the CPU's temperature is high also in normal condition.
This is the response of `lm-sensors`:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +74.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +69.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +67.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Is a problem of the Kernel? I have to wait a new version of the Kernel?
Or is a problem of my PC? I have a "HP Pavilion dv6-1301el".

Comment: uname -a ??????

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Answer (score 0):

Try Jupiter. It gives you a bunch a quick access controls for your hardware including a CPU performance mode.

I have an HP laptop as well and it also gets hot. Jupiter reports that it's normally 85°C, which is pretty hot. However after setting the Performance mode to "Power Saving" the CPU temp dropped a full 10-20°C. Now it's a whole lot cooler and the fan isn't running as hard.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```

For more info and how to change Celsius Temp to Fahrenheit go here:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/jupiter-light-weight-power-and-hardware-control-applet.html

I'm assuming Jupiter is essentially under-clocking the CPU which means that things will be a bit slower. However, that saves power(longer battery), keeps it cool(healthier for the CPU), and if you ever need more speed the tray icon gives you two-click access for cranking it back up.

Comment: duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/jupiter-or-similar-power-saving-app-for-13-04/285681#285681

Comment: Thank you for more answer.
I tried but I think that Jupiter is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04, in fact I had a problem with installation.
I hope that a new update will resolve this problem.

p.s. my cpu's temperature is always about 60°C and more.. Is not normal, isn't?